# Date Extraction Libraries

Tags: date, information-extraction

Does anyone know if there are any libraries around that will extract dates and times given a body of text?  It doesn't matter which language, I'm just looking for a library to play with.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip.pod) module can read dates written in nearly any format.

Examples given on the doc page:

```
$date = ParseDate("today");
$date = ParseDate("1st Thursday in June 1992");
$date = ParseDate("05/10/93");
$date = ParseDate("12:30 Dec 12th 1880");
$date = ParseDate("8:00pm December tenth");
```

Any text that doesn't provide date information is ignored. So you could parse whole documents, looking for dates using this library.